# Selenium-java-3.0.0-beta2 jar files are not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I'm new to selenium, I've tried to automate a simple task, but the build path option is not working in eclipse. I've attached few files here. Please help me to run this code.

Here is the code for that:

```
package seleniumTutorial;

public class SeleniumGoogleMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("jssjohny");
    driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
}
```

}

Here is the download list for selenium :

[image: https]

These are the jar files I've included, but it's not working still :

[image: https]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean not working?? is there any exception or anything else need to share it as well...

Comment: it is working now, Saurabh. Anyway thanks.